# Drawing on a WPF panel, event handler and graphics context

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, graphics

I am new to WPF and come with a WinForms culture.

I need to write an application that paints some graphics using a third-party library that requires to pass a Graphics object or a window Device Context. I face two difficulties:

- I don't see how to create an even handler that would be called when the panel needs refreshing (OnPaint handler, that can be forced with a Refresh call);
- I don't see how to obtain a Graphics from a panel.

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: You may start here: [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-graphics-rendering-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). The graphics engine is completely different than that of WinForms/GDI. There is nothing like OnPaint or Graphics. This may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23974359/1136211.

Comment: You may however host a WinForms component. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/501303/1136211.

Comment: @Clemens: many thanks, this is very helpful. I guess that embedding a Form would be the best way.